# Javascript - How to get Indices of duplicate elements in an array - compared to the other (I'm not sure about the wording)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array `[0,1,0,1]` and this array `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]` and I would like the sum of all indices of the elements in the first array with regard to the second array.

I would like the sum to be 10, not 8 because of duplication in the second array.

Any help would be appreciated.

For example, if I use: `

```
var result = [0,1,0,1].reduce(function (acc,curr,index){
                      acc += [0,0,0,0,1,1].indexOf(curr);
                     return acc;
                      },0);
                  return result;
```

the result is 8, whereas I want it to be 10.

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Comment: your result would work if first array is `[0,1]`. For `[0,1,0,1]`, the result is `5`.

Comment: Please take some time to describe exactly what you  want. Include code you've tried. "I'm not sure of the wording"  means we can't guess.

Comment: I just edited my thread

Comment: What are the rules on editing your current method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum of all indices of the elements in the first array with regard to the second array and reduce the result to 10 you could use this approach.

```
var result = [0,1,0,1].reduce(function (acc,curr,index){
                    if(curr === 0){
                      acc += [0,0,0,0,1,1].indexOf(curr);
                    }
                    else{
                      acc += [0,0,0,0,1,1].lastIndexOf(curr);
                    }
                     return acc;
                      },0);
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I'm sorry I am new to the forum so I don't know the rules yet.

Comment: Thats good.  Could you set this as the accepted answer?  Thank you.